# analytical proof for invertible matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I prove the matrix following type to be invertible, (the dimensions of my actual matrix are larger)

$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ -a_{21} & 1 & -a_{23}&\\-a_{31}&-a_{32}&1 \end{bmatrix}$

Row sum of last $2$ rows is zero, (diagonally dominant matrix).
Since the dimensions of my actual matrix are large I cannot use determined for proof.

Comment: see here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InvertibleMatrixTheorem.html

Comment: It is not clear what the general form of the matrix is in higher dimensions.

Comment: You mention that your matrix's "dimension" is larger, which means to me that it has more rows and columns...and thus there can be huge differences. The determinant of the matrix you wrote is $\;1-a_{23}a_{32}\;$ , so it is invertible iff $\;a_{23}a_{32}\neq1\;$ ...With other matrices you can also check the determinant.

Comment: If the sum of the last two rows is zero, as you say, then the matrix is *not* invertible...

Comment: @5xum, not the sum of the last two rows, but the row sum of each of the last two rows.

Comment: If the elements in the first column are non-zero, then they can be replaced with $0$ to produce a new matrix with the same determinant, which will be strictly diagonally dominant, and thus invertible, as follows from [Gershgorin circle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem).

Comment: @Alexey After the operations you suggest, the determinant is easily computable as $1-a_{23}a_{32}$, which *can* be zero even if $1-a_{23}-a_{21}=0$ and $1-a_{31}-a_{32}=0$.

Comment: @egreg, the OP said (though in parentheses) that the matrix was [diagonally dominant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix).  I imagine that in higher dimensions the determinant would not be easily computable, but my argument would still apply if there are no zeros in the first column.

Comment: @Alexey, ( and egreg) thanks for your answers. In higher dimensions  my matrix will still have; zero row sum, 1's in diagonal and zeros in first row (still diagonally dominant). the solution suggest by Alexey is quite usefull, but what if i have zeros in first column.

Comment: @faisal, I would suggest you to edit your question to better explain the general (higher dimensional) case for which you are looking for a solution.

Comment: Without any additional assumptions, such a matrix has no reason to be invertible.  Consider $a_{21} = a_{31} = 0$, $a_{23} = a_{32} = 1$ in your example.

Comment: Are the off-diagonal terms known to be negative by any chance?

Comment: More generally, if all elements in the first column except for the top one are zero, then the matrix is definitely not invertible.

Comment: @Alexey, the numeric value of all off-diagonal elements is negative, i have used negative sign with off diagonal elements to indicate this.

Comment: Ok, i wonder if this information together with the extra assumption that at least one other entry in the first column is non-zero could be enough...  By the way, the negative sign does not indicate that the number is negative, so you need to state the assumption that $a_{ij}$ are positive as well :).  ($-x$ is positive if $x$ is negative).

Comment: Still there is not enough information to show that is it invertible: what if the last two rows are $0\ \cdots\ 0\ 1\ (-1)$ and $0\ \cdots\ 0\ (-1)\ 1$?

Comment: @Alexey, i really appreciate your answer, they are very useful. (@ negative sign does not indicate that the number is negative) am new to mathematics world :).   thinking over your statement (at least one other entry in the first column is non-zero could be enough). i think you have (almost) solved my problem.

Comment: Trying to play with the idea of the proof of Gershgorin circle theorem in this situation, i think i have figured out the correct answer, but i do not feel like checking the details and writing it down.  I believe that the matrix will fail to be invertible if, and only if, you can select $k$ rows, not including the first one, and $k$ columns, not including the first one, so that every entry which is in one of the selected rows but not in any of the selected column be $0$ (like in the example from my previous comment).

Comment: @ Alexey, Thanks buddy. your comments were very useful for me. Now i have found the solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

since the first row contains all zeros except the first element, i can ignore the first row and first column, without affecting the determinant, and the remaining matrix has ($n-1,n-1$) dimensions. then i add and subtract the first column, $c_{(n-1,1)}$

$A_{(n-1,n-1)}+diag(c_{(n-1,1)})-diag(c_{(n-1,1)})$

since elements of $c_{(n-1,1)}$ are negative $A_{(n-1,n-1)}+diag(c_{(n-1,1)})$ forms a modfied laplacian matrix, $L$, with row sum equal to zero. (see the defination of laplacian matrix)

$L-diag(c_{(n-1,1)})$ is positive definite, since the elements of $c_{(n-1,1)})$ are negative, (proof available in literature).